# Mysql and html timestamps

Tags: php, mysql

how can i get mysql records greater than a timestamp like 1386632264 sent as a GET var from html ? (php and mysql)

mysql time stamp is the current_time_stamp

```
WHERE time>1386632264
```

doesnt work

Here is the query

```
select ua.user_id as member, ua.post_id, pa.user_id, pa.type,
    pa.time, CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) as name,u.thumbnail
from user_activity ua
right join post_activity pa on ua.post_id=pa.post_id
right join users u on pa.user_id=u.user_id
where ua.user_id=6 and time<1386632264
```

Comment: WHat type is the column `time`?

Comment: write code what you tried?

Comment: take the column int(11)

Comment: select ua.user_id as member,ua.post_id,pa.user_id,pa.type,pa.time,CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) as name,u.thumbnail from user_activity ua right join post_activity pa on ua.post_id=pa.post_id right join users u on pa.user_id=u.user_id where ua.user_id=6 and time<1386632264

Comment: mysql time looks like 2013-12-10 10:23:04

Answer (score 1):

Get  mysql `timestamp` with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` . Below is the query.

```
select ua.user_id as member,ua.post_id,pa.user_id,pa.type,pa.time,CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) as name,u.thumbnail from user_activity ua right join post_activity pa on ua.post_id=pa.post_id right join users u on pa.user_id=u.user_id where ua.user_id=6 and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)<1386632264
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp), for example:

```
[your select instructions] WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) >='1196440219'
```

or

```
[your select instructions] WHERE time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP([your webpage date time])
```

This is an example, the value used for the comparison depends on what you take from the webpage.

Comment: doesnt work... how can i convert a time stamp like 2013-12-10 10:23:04
 to 13456752786 ?

Comment: Updated, I misunderstood your question, sorry.